# Probability of colourings of isometry classes of points in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: probability, coloring, symmetry, isometry

I have an interesting puzzle that I am unable to solve.

**Preliminaries:** Suppose that $\mathbb R^2$ is given a *colouring* $\mathbb R^2 \to \{0, \ldots, k-1\}$.
For a given distance $d$, we can compute the *transition probability* by considering arbitrarily many line segments of length $d$, recording the colour at both ends and taking the average. In this manner we obtain a transition matrix $T_d$ in which the entries $T_{d,(i,j)}$ correspond to the probability of encountering colour $j$ at the end of a line segment that starts at a point with colour $i$. From this, one can compute the conditional probability $\mathbb P_i(j)$ of encountering colour $j$ at distance $d$ away from $i$ (sorry for the abuse of notation).

**The problem:** Given a finite metric space $X$ consisting of $n$ points, a colouring $C : X \to \{0, \ldots, k-1\}$ and transition matrices $T_d$ for all pairwise distances $d$ in $X$, what is the probability of encountering colouring $C$ when we embed $X$ isometrically into $\mathbb R^2$?

**What I have tried**: To keep things simple, I considered 3 equidistant points $X = \{ x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ (so we need only a single transition matrix $T$) and 3 possible colours. Suppose that our colouring is $C(x_1) = c_1, C(x_2) = c_2$ and $C(x_3) = c_3$. I figured that the probability of this colouring occurring is invariant under isometries (in this case given by the dihedral group D3) and hence I tried (amongst many other things, most of them wild guesses rather than reasoned approaches):

$$P(C | X) = T(c_1, c_2) (\mathbb P_{c_2}(c_3)\mathbb P_{c_3}(c_1) + \mathbb P_{c_1}(c_3) \mathbb P_{c_3}(c_2)),$$

and

$$P(C | X) = \mathbb P_{c_1}(c_2) \mathbb P_{c_2}(c_3) \mathbb P_{c_3}(c_1) + \mathbb P_{c_1}(c_3) \mathbb P_{c_3}(c_2) \mathbb P_{c_2}(c_1).$$

But both are incorrect: summing these probabilities over all possible permutations does not add up to 1. Ideally, (for computational reasons), I would like to be able to compute the probability for an isometry class without having to compute the number of distinct colourings within a class. I am unsure how to proceed and I am grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you have a coloring $c$ of $\Bbb R^2$, a coloring $d$ of $X$, and transition probabilities associated with $c$, and you want to know the probability that $d=c\circ\phi$ if $\phi$ is selected at random from all isometries $X\to\Bbb R^2$. Is that right? Are you sure the transition probabilities have enough information to determine the answer? And what distribution over isometries are you using?

Comment: @Karl, that is correct. I believe these transition probabilities do contain all required information and the isometries are chosen uniformly at random (although I am not sure how to phrase this rigorously). If I am not mistaken, an equivalent formulation is the following: suppose we know the transition probabilities (but not the colouring of $\mathbb R^2$ per se) and we are given a finite subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^2$ what is the *likelihood* of a colouring $C$ of $X$ given these transition probabilities.

Comment: What definition on $\mathbb R$ you use to define transition probabilities?

Comment: @mihaild. The usual definition. In fact, my question would still stand if you would replace $\mathbb R^2$ by any (decent) metric space.

Comment: @sebman ooops, sorry, I don't now how in my question "distribution" transformed into "definition". The question was, of course, what distribution you use. Anyway, I doubt with any good distribution transition matrix has enough information. For example, coloring into stripes of width $>d$ in order ABACADAEABACADAE... and ABADACAEABADACAE... probably should give the same transition matrix, but you can get BAC (in this order) in the first, but not in the second.

Comment: @mihaild Thanks for your example. You are right, the transition probabilities do not induce a unique colouring. This question is motivated by a problem in applied geoscience where we do not know anything about the distribution of colours on $\mathbb R^2$. The only thing we can practically estimate is the transition probability matrix.